# Building Qt on Raspberry Pi 3: E: Build-dependencies for libqt5gui5 could not be satisfied

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to install Qt for cross compiling on the Raspberry Pi. I am following the instructions from the [Qt Wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/index.php?title=RaspberryPi2EGLFS&oldid=29086).

I have a fresh install of Raspbian Jessie on a new Raspberry Pi 3 Model B.

My issue is on step 3 of the above linked wiki page: `sudo apt-get build-dep libqt5gui5`

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get build-dep libqt5gui5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Picking 'qtbase-opensource-src' as source package instead of 'libqt5gui5'
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgles2-mesa-dev : Depends: libegl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
libopenvg1-mesa-dev : Depends: libegl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Build-dependencies for libqt5gui5 could not be satisfied.
```

I have tried manually installing those dependencies, but run into more of the same issue with other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can replace:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep qt4-x11 libqt5gui5
```

by:

```
apt-get build-dep -y qt4-x11 qtbase-opensource-src
```

This is how we do in our open-source project: [QtRpi](https://github.com/neuronalmotion/qtrpi) to setup the Raspberry Pi sysroot for a Qt cross-compilation.

Check also the project itseft, it "offers an easy-to-use environment to cross-compile Qt application on a Raspberry Pi. This repo contains all the scripts needed to prepare a sysroot, cross-compile Qt and deploy Qt libraries to your Raspberry." Maybe it could be useful for you. More information on the official website: [www.qtrpi.com](http://www.qtrpi.com/)